# How to override System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session (MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I'm trying to override `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["foo"]`.

My problem is that the system is already using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` and I want to add a guid on every session name. (too many to replace)

e.g, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[guid + "foo"]`

Is it possible for me to override the `get` and `set` property?

Comment: If you do not want to use an extension method and change all the already implemented code that calls the string indexer then you could roll your own provider and do it there. See [Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx). You can then implement your "guid prefix" there.

Comment: Any example for the extension? will see what i can do for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use an extension method and change all the already implemented code that calls the string indexer then you could roll your own provider and do it there. See [Implementing a Session-State Store Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587.aspx). You can then implement your "guid prefix" there.

Here is an example of an extension method. I have no idea where you are getting `guid` from, you never mentioned this but you can take this example and add it yourself.

```
public static class HttpSessionStateExtension
{
    public static object Get(this System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState session, string key)
    {
        var guid = ???; // no idea where or how you are getting guid, you never explained that in your question
        return session[guid + key];
    }
}

// in other methods you can then call it the same as you would the indexer
var result = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Get("foo");
```

Comment: I think he meant `new System.Guid.ToString()`